# DropDown on MouseOver

Tags: jquery, html, css

Want to know how can i achieve this with the below code snippet:
Whenever i mouseover over Test i want to show some dropdown list onmouseover

```
<div id="appLinks">
    <ul id="appLinks_list" class="nav">
        <span id="appLink_csrname" class="ui-state-default csrname">Test</span>
            <li id="appLink_about" rtlOrder="3"><a title="tooltip"   href="javascript:openAboutDialog();">&nbsp; About</a></li>
        </span>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, only `li` elements can be direct children of a `ul`.

Comment: might be you are correct, but this is already working code i just need to provide functionality for mouseover as i am new to web based technologies so seeking out some help

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI you don't need any javascript to do that.

```
ul li { display:none; }
ul:hover li { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="outer">
  Outer
  <div id="inner">
    Inner
  </div>
</div>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
 </div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Jquery :

```
 $( "#outer" ).mouseover(function() {
 $( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .mouseover() called.</div>" );
 });
```

Dont forget the include Jquery in our 
Example:

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<ul class="my_list">
      <span>text</span>
               <li>hi</li>
               <li>i</li>
               <li>am</li>
               <li>archie</li>
               <li>abhi</li>
             </ul>
```

**css:**`

```
.my_list li{
            display: none;
              }
        .my_list:hover  li{
          display: block;
        }
```

**javascript**

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".my_list").mouseleave(function(){
          $(".my_list li").css("display","none");
        });
        $(".my_list").mouseover(function(){
          $(".my_list li").css("display","block");
        });
     });
     </script>
```